# How can I make Apache set the REMOTE_USER environment variable for Django?

Tags: python, django, apache

I'm writing a Django application that uses HTTP basic auth to log a user in. Django's documentation on [how to authenticate using REMOTE_USER](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/auth-remote-user/) makes it sound totally trivial to have your webserver set the REMOTE_USER header and have it log in. I can't for the life of me figure out how to do that. This is my Apache configuration for mod_auth_basic:

```
<Location />
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "restriced"
    AuthUserFile "<config_root>/httpd/passwd/passwords"
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

The authentication works great, but no headers like REMOTE_USER appear in request.META. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I have a very similar problem. Have you figured out how to do this? I never see the `authenticate` method of `RemoteUserBackend` being called, which explains why `request.META` does not contain the setting, but I do not know what I need to change...